# Ember.js send mail

Tags: ember.js

Hey is there any way to send mail to someone through ember.js .. I had made a contact form and i am using php for sending mail. There is a way of doing it with ajax requests with node.js but is there any way to do it with ember.js.

Answer (score 2):

Ember lives on the client, so not really. You could just open a mailto: link, and get them to email in their client (e.g. Outlook, Mail, Thunderbird), but that's likely not what you want.

Typically you'd still do an ajax request back to a server side script, in PHP, Ruby, Node.js or whatever.

Comment: Ya I have done it with ajax request back to server side script in node.js.. thanks.. :)